# In RSpec - how can I test if one attribute is less (or more) than another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

In my app I want to have a `Car` model.

It will have two fields among others: `date_from` and `date_till` (to specify a period of time someone was using it).

And I want the model to validate that date_from should be less or equal than date_till.

My model_spec.rb draft looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Car do
  it {should validate_presence_of(:model)}
  it {should validate_presence_of(:made)}

  it "should have date_till only if it has date_from"
  its "date_till should be >= date_from"
end
```

Obviously, I can just write a "long" test where I will try to set date_till to be greater than date_from - and the model just should be invalid. But maybe there are some elegant ways to do it?

So, how can I (using RSpec matchers) validate that one field is not greater than another?

**upd:**
I looked at @itsnikolay's answer and coded it like that:

```
it "does not allow date_till less than date_from" do
  subject.date_from = Date.today
  subject.date_till = Date.today - 1.day

  subject.valid?.should be_false
end
```

Had to do it without matchers. Well, not a tragedy :)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It is generally [recommended to use expect, not should](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md).

For instance:

```
  expect(@car.date_from).to be <= @car.date_till
```

Resources:
- [BetterSpecs examples](http://betterspecs.org/#expect)
- [Rspec Docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames)

Comment: and if you are into one-liners: `it { is_expected.to be <= @car.date_till }`

Answer (score 14):

Just use `<=`

```
date_from.should be <= date_till
```

Comment: if they both initialized as nil? test will pass, but does it cover all the behavior?

Answer (score 7):

Or in new syntax

```
expect(date_from).to be <= date_till
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@car = Car.create \
  name:      'Buggy',
  date_from: Date.today + 1.day,
  date_till: Date.today + 2.day

expect(@car.date_from).to be <= @car.date_till
```

More details: [RSpec Comparison matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/comparison-matchers)

Answer (score 0):

`expect(value1 < value2).to be_truthy` should do it